# I am getting a constant sending request in postman

Tags: express, web, postman, mern

I am doing a post request using postman to my server but instead, I am getting a sending request display on my postman. It is not showing any error and I am pretty new to this technology. Please help.

127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/login    -- using this as the route.

router.post('/login', authController.login);  // this is the routing code

// This is the function that is called on post request.

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // 1) if email pass exist
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400));
  }
  // 2). if user exist and pass is correct
  const user = User.findOne({ email: email });

  // 3). if everything is ok send token to client
  const token = '';
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
  });
};
```

// This is the appError Class

```
class AppError extends Error {
  constructor(message, statusCode) {
    super(message);

    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'fail' : 'error';
    this.isOperational = true;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

module.exports = AppError;
```

When i am using the postman it should run the statement

return next(new AppError(`Please provide an email',404));
but it is not running.

I am attaching all the references [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm8zO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGLn7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRB6w.png)

Comment: are you sure your server is up and running? have you tried `localhost:8000` instead of `127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: @JoshPart thanx for replying.
Yes i have tried using localhost:8000 too.
Its showing the same thing